# Many different class objects listening to a single event c#

Tags: c#, events

I have a camera handler class that everytime it receives a frame data, it invokes an event, as below:

```
public delegate void FrameAcquiredCallback(byte[] frameData);

public void OnFrameArrived(MediaFrameReader sender, MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs args) {
     FrameAcquired.Invoke(buffer); // buffer is a byte[] that I set up previously.
}
```

Once a class object wants access to that `byte[] frameData`, all it has to do is subscribe to the event, as below:

```
public class Start1
{
     public CameraHandler camera;
     public void Start()
     {
        camera = new CameraHandler();
        camera.FrameAcquired += eventTest1;
     }
     public static void eventTest1(byte[] frameData)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Received1");
     }
}
```

Now what I want to do is have not just one class, but multiple different class objects to be able to subscribe to the same event and have access to the `byte[] frameData`.

When I create a new class and subscribe similarly, I now have two instantiation of CameraHandlers, which will not work.

What is the most clean and "norm" way of implementing this functionality?

Comment: Events are inherently multicast capable. They are basically multicast delegates with add/remove accessors. There is a whole intro on that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is perfectly fine. If you are only accessing one camera, you just need one CameraHandler object to create multiple eventhandlers.

However, if you have access to multiple cameras at the same time, then you would need a list of cameraHandlers, e.g. `List<CameraHandler> cameras` so that you can get the data you want from a specific camera. Should be aware of synchronization if you are working with IMU information though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook as many listeners as you want via [custom event accessors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-implement-custom-event-accessors).

```
public class Start1
{
  public EventHandler FrameAcquired
  {
    add 
    {
      this.camera.FrameAcquired += value;
    }
    remove
    {
      this.camera.FrameAcquired -= value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that, but that would only work if the eventHandlers in different classes subscribe to the same CameraHandler object. 
I was talking about if there is a way to do the same with many instantiated CameraHandler objects.

Comment: I'd also recommend you make the camera field private

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at the event aggregator pattern.
https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/event-aggregator.html
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/866547/Publisher-Subscriber-pattern-with-Event-Delegate-a